# How to create image from silverlight control or its part?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I would like to save up my current form (actually its part, a specific kind of crop image) look  and use it as image on another silverlight control/page (dynamiccally and programatically obviously)

I have found a question here about this which is 2 years old and its answered there is no way to do so in SL2.0

[Silverlight: Create image from silverlight controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668090/silverlight-create-image-from-silverlight-controls)

I wasn't able to find answer in internet so I am asking whether it is possible now in SL4.0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the WriteableBitmap class.

```
int PreviewWidth = 200;
int PreviewHeight = 200;
var writeableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(PreviewWidth, PreviewHeight);
writeableBitmap.Render(<somecontrol>, null);
writeableBitmap.Invalidate();
```

Answer (score 0):

In one of my WPF projects I use RenderTargetBitmap to render the contents of a control to a bitmap. I found that you can't use that in Silverlight, but I did a search and found a [forum post](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/193629/448932.aspx) mentioning that [WriteableBitmap.Render](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.render%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) might do a similar thing in Silverlight.